# Clicking First Visible Element of a Certain Class in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have a webpage that looks something like this:

```
<div class="itemHolder" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="itemHolder" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="itemHolder" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="itemHolder"></div> 
<div class="itemHolder" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="itemHolder" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="itemHolder"></div>
<div class="itemHolder" style="display: none;"></div>
```

I need to double click on the first itemHolder that is visible. I've tried to use the following but I'm getting an error

```
myItem = driver.find_element_by_class("itemHolder")

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(myItem)
actions.double_click(myItem)
actions.perform()
```

> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Element is not
>   clickable at point (310.5, 208). Other element would receive the click

So my question is, how can I click on the ***first visible itemHolder*** in selenium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look for element that doesn't have attribute `style="display: none;"`

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.itemHolder:not([style="display: none;"])')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly. accepting this answer in 11 minutes (as fast as I can)